# Kernel opps doesnt break into kgdb stub

Tags: linux-kernel

This is annoying.  I have the kernel built with debugging, kgdb over serial, and it works fine for normal debugging.  But when an oops occurs it doesnt break into the debugger if it is running or allow me to start the debugger and examine the oops.  This is particularly annoying as staticly declared functions dont show up in the oops stack trace making it hard to know exactly what code was called.

BTW this is running on an ARM 11 chip.

Anyone else seen this or know of a way to get it working?

Thanks in advance.